# How to create a server side timer/countdown in Django Channels?

Tags: python, django, websocket, python-asyncio

Lets say I am building a pub-quiz app with Django Channels (Websockets). There are 10 questions and each question has a time limit and a button to add extra 5 seconds.

I know a possibility would be to haver the timer client-side, but I need it to be server-side to avoid tampering with the Js causing problems since there are many players involved.

How can I create a timer in Django, server-side? Once the timer is up, it would need to call a function to fetch the next question. I would know how to do it with a while loop:

```
    While True:
        if datetime.now() == question_end_time:
             fetch_next_question()
```

But from what I have read this does not seem to be a good idea due to blocking the thread. Is there any other way how to check every second if the time for the question is up and is so, call a function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What about going the other way with it, and instead of checking every second you instead set something to happen at the end of a timer.

Use javascript to create a timer, and when the timer ends the javascript will call the django url, with ajax.

That way you aren't monitoring every second.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I would like to refrain from using the client-side for the counter for several reasons and rather wish to use the backend somehow (is maybe Celery a good option, even for repeated 1 second tasks?)